# Batch script that can find the Startup folder on any Windows 10 PC using environment variables

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

How do I write a batch script that, no matter which Windows 10 PC it runs on, no matter what the name of the user, will install a file in C:\Users\Mr x\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup, using environment variables?

Comment: [`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)

Comment: Even better `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, see [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access files no matter the username is to use the `%USERNAME%` variable in the file destination.

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\<<path>>`

Comment: That's a bad idea. The environment variable __USERNAME__ holds only the user account name. The *standard* path for user profile is `C:\User\%USERNAME%` since Windows Vista. But every user has the freedom to install Windows on a different drive than drive C: or have the user profile stored in a different directory. And additionally every user has the freedom to use a different application data directory than what Windows defines by default. On all my Windows computers usage of `%APPDATA%` would work, but not `C:\Users\%USERNAME%` as I'm not using the Windows default paths.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommed `%APPDATA%`. [@Diriector_Doc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3470353/diriector-doc)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44444931/11958176) could work, but if a user installs Windows, on a E:/ drive instead, it could make the program fail.

However, from personal UX (user experience), you cannot write/copy any files to the Startup folder. Windows just ignores the command and continues your script - no errors or changes to `%ERRORLEVEL%`.